# Check-o-matic? is there such a thing?

Tags: payments

Several insurance companies use a service called Check-o-matic , where they deduct from the users checking account. Has anyone seen a service like this? It would be a competitor to paypal. 
I know paypal with deduct from a checking, but they are looking for a specific service. I don't know if one exists, but all the insurance companies call it the same, Check-o-matic.

Comment: You couldn't Google this?

Comment: John, why do you have to be so nasty? This is why I don't come here often.

Comment: [We are not your personal research assistants](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553). You are *expected* to have researched any questions or issues you have *before* you come to this site to ask for help. Especially for such a simple question such as this. You could have **easily** found your answer using Google.

Comment: I guess this is not a safe place to come and ask questions.

Comment: @Joe this is also a really bad question for se: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/

Comment: @Christofian, well since I received the exact answer I needed in less than 24hrs, I don't think it was a guessing game. There was 1 answer and it was perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system you're taking about is called [Direct Debit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_debit). There are quite a [number of providers](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=direct%20debit#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&rlz=1C1SKPM_enGB448GB448&q=direct%20debit%20service%20usa&oq=direct%20debit%20service%20usa&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=serp.3...8170.11174.0.11413.12.8.0.4.4.0.114.544.7j1.8.0...0.0.m3NCIVwDHFk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=c42e58457be33447&biw=1920&bih=955).